# What to do when accidentally overfilled a car battery

Tags: battery, toyota

My car, a 2003 Toyota Kijang (known as Toyota Revo in other markets) uses a *non* maintenance-free battery that has to be topped up every now and then with distilled water.

Today, while filling it up, I accidentally overfilled the battery (I was startled by something and my hand flinched). The liquid overflowed on top of the battery. So I closed the cap and poured water on top of the spills to dilute and wash it away.

What should I do next? I think I don't have a tool to suck out the excess fluid from the battery, and the battery is too heavy for me to lift out of the engine bay.

Comment: If you do this again, consider using baking soda to neutralize the acid instead of just diluting it with water.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try removing some with a specific gravity checking bulb with glass tube. If you don't have one a simple plastic hypodermic syringe (50ml) will do the trick. Do not keep the acid in the syringe for a long time though.

Answer (score 2):

I think you've done all you can do by washing the excess away. Accidents happen and you've done the best you can. I don't think you've ruined your battery, though the electrolyte may be a little low in the cell you overfilled. As long as you can put the cap back on, I'm fairly sure you are in good shape.